# master local ref ''local out of date'' after fetching in git

Tags: git

I am checking a private remote repo using:

```
git remote show origin
```

I get

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: 
  Push  URL: 
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master                                      tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master            merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master            pushes to master            (local out of date)
```

I read  `(local out of date)` so I do

```
git fetch origin
```

then I repeat the `git remote show origin` but master is `still out of date`.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has an interface which allows changes in the remote repository to be visible in the local setup via something called remote tracking branches.  These remote tracking branches, which are actually local, mainly exist to represent the state of the *remote* repository at some point in time.  By default, a local branch called `master` would *track* a remote tracking branch called `origin/master`.  This should not be confused with `origin master`, which you might see in a Git command to refer to the true remote `master` branch which lives on your Git repo.

When you do `git fetch origin`, you update the remote tracking branch for `master`, but *not* the actual local `master` branch.  To make the out of date message go away, you can bring those latest changes into the local `master`:

```
git merge origin/master
```

You could also rebase your local branch on the remote `master`:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Note that most of the time you would probably just update your working local branch via a `git pull`, e.g.

```
git pull origin master
# or
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Comment: make sense. I guess your solution works when the local master is the current branch (or in general?)

Comment: I assumed the branch is called `master` but it could be called anything.

Comment: I mean I have to do checkout master before the merge, otherwise I might loose changes to my current checked out local branch if that is not master (right?)

Comment: Well merging or rebasing is inherently done on the current branch, so yes if you want to update your local `master` branch then you would generally need to check it out first.